# $GCH$ and special Aronszajn trees

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, gch

> **Question.** Does $\text{GCH}$ imply the existence of a non-special $\aleph_2$-Aronszajn tree ?

**Remark 1.** By a result of Jensen, it is consistent that $\text{GCH}$ holds and all $\aleph_1$-Aronszajn trees are special.

**Remark 2.** The above question is related to the famous question ``does $\text{GCH}$ imply the existence of an $\aleph_2$-Souslin tree ?''.

Comment: Here is a reference to [your recent joint paper with Yair Chayut](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/~golshani/Papers/Special%20Aronszajn%20tree%20property.pdf) on this topic for further reading of those who might be interested in knowing more!

Comment: Funny. This getting bumped just when David Asperó is about to give a talk about this very topic in Amsterdam at the KNAW 2018 Colloquium... :P

Comment: @AsafKaragila Aspero's silde is now avalable [Special $\aleph_2$-Aronszajn trees and GCH](http://events.illc.uva.nl/KNAW2018/Amsterdam2018.pdf). I may post an answer to this question later.

Comment: Mohammad, maybe it's time to point out your new paper on arXiv? The community service bumped this up again, today. I think it knows.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out the answer to the question is no.
David Aspero and I, have proved the following:

**Theorem.** Assuming the existence of a weakly compact cardinal, there exists a generic extension of the universe in which $GCH$ holds and all $\aleph_2$-Aronszajn trees are special.

See [The special Aronszajn tree property at $\aleph_2$ and $GCH$](https://archive.uea.ac.uk/~bfe12ncu/Special-aleph-2-A-trees-GCH.pdf).

> Comments and suggestions on the paper are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a result by Specker: Specker, E.. "[Sur un problème de Sikorski](https://eudml.org/doc/209986)." Colloquium Mathematicae 2.1 (1949): 9-12.

Comment: Torres-Prez. Your answer is not correct, Specker's construction gives a special $\aleph_2$-Aronszajn tree. I'm asking for non-special ones.

Comment: In fact I think the question is open and quite old.